# Did Kevin spill real chili?

Tags: props, the-office

In the Office season 5 episode 26 in the cold open Kevin makes a big pot of chili and spills it all on the office floor when bringing it in.

Is it real chili? I am wondering if there is any episode commentary confirming if they actually made a huge pot of chili to spill or if it was a prop of some kind of fake chili?

This is more just a curiosity about the behind the scenes of this scene. Because theoretically they must've have to gotten it in one take or as few takes as possible since Kevin spills the chili right on the carpet floor and that would involve having to rip out the carpet if he broke and started laughing or anything mid-take. And the pot of chili is huge so I wonder how much actual chili they must've used for this shot.

Does anyone have any background information on this scene? Thanks!

Comment: Regardless of the realness of the chili and even if they did do it in one take, they would still need to rip the carpet up since the chili stain was not going to be a recurring feature in future episodes.

Comment: They never use real chill in movies, it doesn't look right. They use [porridge painted like chili](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Recap/TheSimpsonsS7E2RadioactiveMan) instead.

Comment: @Flater fair enough. You got me. I just wanted to know if they used real chili. And that is also true in regards of the chili stain not being a recurring feature. I was more just curious about the behind the scenes of that shot.

Comment: The title asks whether Kevin spilled real chili, but the question seems to be asking whether Brian Baumgartner spilled real chili.

Comment: @Acccumulation I mean you are technically right but I'd rather keep the question title to say Kevin so Office fans would understand right away which scene I mean

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Brian Baumgartner (Kevin) explains this in the video below:

He talks about the carpet, and he explains that they prepared 3 takes for this scene, but it wasn't necessary, one take did it.

It was also real chili.